# param is missing or the value is empty: center

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I am new to rails I have seen this question is often ask but I am still having some problem .Can anyone tell me where I am doing wrong.

[center_controller]

```
class CentersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @centers=Center.all
  end 

  def new
  @center=Center.new
  end

  def create
    @center=Center.new(para)
    if @center.save
        flash[:notice] = "success man."
            redirect_to @center
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
    def para
     params.require(:center).permit(:registration_number,:registration_date,
:tin_number,:no_of_trainers,:total_numbers,:name,:address,
:contact_no,:registration_fee,:monthly_fee,:status,:sector_id)
    end

end
```

[center/index.html.erb]

```
<%=form_for :centers_index_path do |f| %>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Centers</legend>
                <div>
                    <%= f.text_field :registration_number, :placeholder=>"Enter registration number" %>
                </div>
                  <div>
                    <%= f.text_field :registration_date, :placeholder=>"Enter registration date" %>
                </div>
<%= f.submit :submit %>    
            </fieldset>    
        <% end %>
  <br>
```

[center.rb]

```
class Center < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :registration_number,presence: true
validates :registration_date
end
```

[migration]

```
class CreateCenters < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :centers do |t|
        t.integer :registration_number
        t.date :registration_date
        t.integer :tin_number
        t.integer :no_of_trainers
        t.integer :total_numbers
        t.string :name
        t.string :address
        t.string :contact_no
        t.integer :registration_fee
        t.integer :monthly_fee
        t.integer :status
        t.integer :sector_id
        t.timestamps
    end
    add_foreign_key :centers,:sectors
  end
```

getting this error on console

```
 Started POST "/centers" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-20 15:00:47 +0530
    Processing by CentersController#create as HTML
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"11rrttKOGdWrCClqnB/aTuHWLT4UsoQRWkpiwwk6bBxgSBO85f532LytX3d6rJml8cW3lMjnvB6eUpAeTHBA6A==", "centers_index_path"=>{"text"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"submit"}
    Completed 400 Bad Request in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Could you update the view which is  using for `POST /centers`, like `index.html.erb` is not the related one?

Comment: Can you show your new.erb and your routes. If the form is in the index file, why are your rendering new on error?

Comment: IN the code which is show it is my complete index.html.erb .do i need to add all the fields in my view which i have listed in my params

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: yes it is working now

Comment: Great! I am glad I could help and I hope you learned a bit more about Rails :-)

Comment: yeah thank you ...I am building a small website for myself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `@center` in the `form_for`!

```
<%=form_for @center do |f| %>
```

This will bind the form to your model and the params actually go where they need to!

On the `new` action (GET) it will create a new empty `center` and on the `create` action (POST) it will fill the `center` with the data of the form!

That should work!

**UPDATE:**

You are not using the new action, you should have the form as a partial inside a file called `new.html.erb` and then call new.

*I would suggest that you **generate a new scaffold** to see how the REST setup should look like and take it from there. You can do that like that:*

```
rails g scaffold my_center registration_number:integer registration_date:date tin_number:integer ... ...
```

then:

```
rake db:migrate
```

This will give you a working example of my_center and is very easy to adjust!

Comment: If I am using @centers it is showing me error (undefined method `to_key' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation [] thats why I am using centers_index_path

Comment: You are not using the new action, you should have the form as a partial inside a file called new.html.erb and then call new.

Comment: I would suggest that you generate a new scaffold and look at that very setup and go from there:

rails g scaffold my_center registration_number:integer registration_date:date  tin_number:integer ...

Comment: so i should move my code from index.html.erb to new.html.erb ??

Comment: index.html.erb should list all the centers. new.html.erb should be the entry point to create a new center which then will be shown at index.html.erb after it is created. Try the scaffold and you will see what I mean!

Answer (score 1):

Please check your form_for
If you need to pass form values to create action then following code is sufficient.

```
<%= form_for @center do |f| %>
<% end  %>
```

If you want to pass form values to another action then you need to set url path for it.

```
<%= form_for @center, url: center_save_path do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: If I am using @centers it is showing me error (undefined method `to_key' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation [] thats why I am using centers_index_path

Comment: ok,  so if your form is on index page then also declare   @center=Center.new in your def index, so this will create new object for center.